# Will Anaconda for Python 2.7 for Windows 7 work on Python 2.6 on Windows?

Tags: anaconda, windows-7-x64, python-2.6

I have a Windows 7 (64-bit) laptop, still quite powerful for testing and development.
I just installed Python 2.6 for Windows 7 (64-bit) -- because that is the latest I can get.  I am following the free Python video courses in MIT Open Courseware (OCW).
Based on the book by Prof. Guttag, Anaconda seems most suitable as the IDE for Python beginners.

My question is: will Anaconda for Python 2.7 (there is no download "for Python 2.6" as of Feb 19, 2019) work?
Would be grateful for any advice/tips/guidance.

Comment: Anaconda isn't an IDE -- it is more like a package manager of programs / software.  So that you can easily replicate an environment from one computer to another.  I don't know about the book by Prof. Guttag, but it sounds like you should be looking for something else.  (It is good practice to use Anaconda, but as for an IDE, you might want to look somewhere else.)  As for Python 2.6 vs 2.7, there is a small difference between them.  There is a bigger concern between 3.x vs 2.x .

Comment: My sincerest thanks for clarifying, much appreciated.